# Feature importances and selection per target variable

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Since i have too many features I wanted to lower the amount and found a way with this `RandomForestClassifier` to identify feature importances.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, random_state=42)
rnd_clf.fit(X, y)




a = {name: importance for name, importance in zip(NUMBER, rnd_clf.feature_importances_)}

df = pd.DataFrame(list(a.items()), columns=['name', 'importance'])

df2 = df.sort_values('importance',ascending=False)
```

But since I have 6 target variables I wanted to identify which features matter per target variable and not those for all in the above code.

I tried to remove the other target variables in the learningset but that did not work because all the importances where set to 0. How can I fix this?

EDIT: 
Example data: Partij is Y. Other variables are X (and much more)

```
gemeente    Partij  Perioden    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Totale bevolking (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Geslacht/Mannen (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Geslacht/Vrouwen (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/Jonger dan 5 jaar (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/5 tot 10 jaar (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/10 tot 15 jaar (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/15 tot 20 jaar (aantal)
0   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2007    135648.0    66669.0 68979.0 7986.0  7809.0  7514.0  7612.0  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2008    136481.0    67047.0 69434.0 7885.0  7853.0  7517.0  7680.0  ... 5.8 8.6 41.3    5.2 4.0 20.0    4.0 5.0 25.0    3.0
2   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2009    137775.0    67715.0 70060.0 7915.0  7890.0  7497.0  7628.0  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2010    139607.0    68628.0 70979.0 8127.0  7852.0  7527.0  7752.0  ... 5.6 8.4 40.7    5.4 4.0 20.0    3.0 5.0 24.0    3.0
4   Aa en Hunze PVDA    2007    25563.0 12653.0 12910.0
```

Comment: `feature_importances` are supposed to be interpreted as more it is, better it is. You have sorted by `ascending=True`, setting it to `False` might help

Comment: That doesn't matter since I still don't know the most important features per target variable.

Comment: can you post some sample data on `X` and `y` ?

Comment: What do you mean by per target variable? Do you have multiple targets? Are you talking about multiclass (single label per sample, but can have more than 2 labels in data), or multi-label (single sample can have multiple labels)?

Comment: per target variable means that I want to specify which features matter for which target variable. So Which for VVD and which for PVDA and there are others in the dataset. I think I mean multi-class.

Comment: Then you can do this by One-vs-rest strategy I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 6 datasets for the 6 target variables if you want to know which features matter per target variable.

To explore the importance of the features, there are several more possibilities than the feature_importance method of a tree-based-model.

- correlation coefficient
- Model-based ranking
- Stability selection
- RFE